# Blazor batch calls to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, batching

I´m using Blazor and I need to invoke JS functions from C#. I have read that the calls to JS are very consuming so they should be minimized and/or batched.
What is exactly batching? How can I batch the calls to JS? Is it going to improve the performance of my code or it´s just losing my time?

Comment: You first need to give some indication of what you are doing.  This question is too generalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99.9% of the time the performance considerations are not worth worrying about.

If you truly do need to worry then you could write yourself a JavaScript function that takes, as an argument, a list of other JavaScript function calls to make and that then makes those calls.  This would keep your interopped call count at 1.

The performance / code complexity trade off doesn't make sense to me, but there are more use-cases in heaven and Earth than I can imagine.

Here is a decent post proposing another batching solution implementation.  The conclusion of the post, however, is that it wasn't worth it.

https://blog.zhaytam.com/2021/09/23/blazor-js-interop-batching/

Comment: A good use-case for batching is canvas animation (e.g. games). To get 60 FPS you'd need to call canvas methods thousands of times a second. I'm able to achieve 60 FPS with this package https://github.com/excubo-ag/Blazor.Canvas that uses batching (there is a custom batching mechanism inside that package) but there is a room for improvement.